# The view found at was not created when Razor error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mono, autofac

I use MVC4 with mono 3.2.3 and I notice that if I create an error in Razor cshtml file:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 8aaaa; i++)
```

Following error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>       ...

I remember that on Windows there's a smart Razor compilation error message. How could I enable such feature under mono platform?

Related question: [MVC5 Autofac: The view found at was not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488330/mvc5-autofac-the-view-found-at-was-not-created)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, the Razor files are compiled individually and *maybe* with better support for design type error checking.

With the Mono runtime of .NET, all views are group compiled by controller and even with 1 Razor syntax error, none of the views under that Controller will be compiled. This means the views really don't exist and they throw the "view not found" error.

I doubt if there is any setting which can get the behavior like on Windows with the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in .csproj file.It will compile views

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```